# Alexa Skills Kit: How to add an image to a standard card using JS

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've been building off the examples in [alexa-skills-kit-js/samples/](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js/tree/master/samples)

but they don't have any where you add an image to the response card.

`response.askWithCard(speechOutput, repromptOutput, cardTitle, cardContent);`

Where does the image go? The `cardContent` is usually a string. Do I just make it into an object containing an image?

Answer (score 3):

I followed a [reply](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/28343/how-too-add-an-image-to-a-custom-skills-card-using.html) to a similar question on the Amazon developer support forums from Mark Stringer:

> I have been struggling with this myself and now have it working. If
>   you are using the sample AlexaSkill.js module that Amazon provide then
>   you need to add a couple of sections to it to deal with picture cards.
>
> In the buildSpeechletResponse section add this after the similar type
>   "Simple" section:
>
> ```
>     if (options.cardSmallImageURL && options.cardLargeImageURL) {
>         alexaResponse.card = {
>             type: "Standard",
>             title: options.cardTitle,
>             text: options.cardContent,
>             image: {
>                 smallImageUrl: options.cardSmallImageURL,
>                 largeImageUrl: options.cardLargeImageURL
>             }
>         };
>     }
> ```
>
> Then after the askWithCard definition further down add this:
>
> ```
>     askWithPictureCard: function(speechOutput, repromptSpeech, cardTitle, cardContent, smallImageURL, largeImageURL) {
>         this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
>             session: this._session,
>             output: speechOutput,
>             reprompt: repromptSpeech,
>             cardTitle: cardTitle,
>             cardContent: cardContent,
>             cardSmallImageURL: smallImageURL,
>             cardLargeImageURL: largeImageURL,
>             shouldEndSession: false
>         }));
> ```
>
> Now you can call it, probably using variables rather than constants I
>   was testing with using;
>
> response.askWithPictureCard('This is the speech output', 'This is the
>   reprompt', 'this is the card title', 'This is the card text, note the
>   field is called text not cardContent',
>   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/thisisthesmallpictureurl-small.jpg',
>   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/thisisthebigpictureurl-big.jpg' );
>
> Then follow a similar process to add a tellWithPictureCard function.

There's one small typo in the code there where Stringer put *crd* when he meant *card* which I corrected in my paste above. Other than that this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like 'Simple' is hardcoded, and 'Standard' cards are required for small and large image URLs. Here is the code from

https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js/blob/master/samples/historyBuff/src/AlexaSkill.js#L142

```
    if (options.cardTitle && options.cardContent) {
        alexaResponse.card = {
            type: "Simple",
            title: options.cardTitle,
            content: options.cardContent
        };
    }
```

You would need to modify your local copy of AlexaSkill.js to add the functionality.

Here is API usage of Flask-Ask library (mine) showing how cards work:

https://johnwheeler.org/flask-ask/responses.html#displaying-cards-in-the-alexa-smartphone-tablet-app